# does kashering require the vessel to be unused for 24 hours (ben yomo)?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

If someone is going to be kashering via hagala or by libun does the cleaning of the items prior to kashering require the vessel or utensil also be left unused for 24 hours? If yes, why?

Comment: Why do you think it might need that?

Answer (score 2):

Kashering a stove using Libun Kal requires waiting 24 hours (according to Rav Ovadia, Hilchos Pesach) and also Rabbi Blumenkranz writes the same thing in his Laws of Pesach guide.  According to Rabbi Blumenkranz Libun Gamur does not require waiting 24 hours.  He does say that Hagoloh requires waiting 24 hours before purging.

If you are asking whether there is an additional 24 hour period related to cleaning the items, the answer is no.  The process is:

1. clean
2. wait 24 hours
3. kasher

Here is [link](http://newb.co.il/?p=1311) to a summary of Rav Ovadia's psak on kashering various utensils for Pesach. (Sorry it's in עברית).

Comment: "according to Rav Ovadia, Hilchos Pesach" Which work of his? Are you referring to Yalkut Yossef (written by his son)?

Comment: Sorry - going on memory -- I believe it was חזון עובדיה which I was reading in shul.  The website link I posted is someone's קיצור version, but said essentially the same thing.  (Although I think I recall from חזון עובדיה that he wrote to wait 24 hours first, and then clean.)

Answer (score 1):

SA YD 121, 2, annotations from RM Issarles:

> ‏ אין להגעיל שום כלי כל זמן שהוא בן יומו (טור) ‏
>
> We have not to clean vessels by hag'ala when they were used (with non Kasher food, or even with water only )
>
> ואין מגעילין הכלי עד שלא יהא בן יומו, או שיהיו במים שמגעילין בו ס' כנגדו. אבל אם הוא בן יומו ואין במים ס' כנגדו, לא עלתה לו הגעלה, ולא עוד אלא אפילו הכלי שמגעילו בתוכו ג"כ נאסר אם היא של היתר. וכן אם מגעיל כלי של בשר לאכול בו חלב או איפכא, צריך שלא יהא בן יומו. ואם מגעיל בכלי של איסור, צריך שלא יהא בן יומו, כי המים נאסרים אם אין בהם שיעור ס' כנגד הכלי, ואי אפשר שיהא בהן ס' כנגדו דבכולו משערינן ואין שום כלי מחזיק שיעור ס' כנגדו.

ואיזהו שאינו בן יומו - פירש ר"ת כל שעבר עליו לילה אחת בלא תבשיל, אפילו בשלו בו אתמול בערב, מיד בבקר אינו בן יומו. ור"י פירש שצריך שישהא מעת לעת, וכן עיקר. ואם בתוך מעת לעת חממו בו אפילו מים לבדם, צריך לשהות מעת לעת לבישול המים. אבל בבשר בחלב אינו כן, אם בשל בה מים לבדם אחר בישול הבשר ובא להכשירה לחלב, אין צריך לשהות מעת לעת אחר בישול המים אלא אחר בישול הבשר. the same day (from the words of the Tur).

Baer Heytev sk 2.

> אבל אם יש במי הגעלה ס' כנגדו מותר להגעילו אף כשהוא ב"י
>
> If there is a proportion of 1/60 between the volume of the vessel and the quantity of water, there is no need to wait.

---

As mentioned, the source is in Tur on the same siman (the source of Rishonim is the Gemara in Masechet Avoda Zara).

> ואין מגעילין הכלי עד שלא יהא בן יומו, או שיהיו במים שמגעילין בו ס' כנגדו. אבל אם הוא בן יומו ואין במים ס' כנגדו, לא עלתה לו הגעלה, ולא עוד אלא אפילו הכלי שמגעילו בתוכו ג"כ נאסר אם היא של היתר. ‏
>
> He adds that if one makes hag'ala of a vessel which was used the same day, the container itself becomes non kasher.
>
> וכן אם מגעיל כלי של בשר לאכול בו חלב או איפכא, צריך שלא יהא בן יומו. ‏
>
> To make hag'ala of a meat'd vessel in way to eat dairy with it, we need also to wait one day after use with meat.

ואם מגעיל בכלי של איסור, צריך שלא יהא בן יומו, כי המים נאסרים אם אין בהם שיעור ס' כנגד הכלי, ואי אפשר שיהא בהן ס' כנגדו דבכולו משערינן ואין שום כלי מחזיק שיעור ס' כנגדו.‏

> ... the reason we need to wait for a non kasher vesdel is that the vessel makes the water non kasher because of the taste of non kasher food. Most vessels do
>
> ואיזהו שאינו בן יומו - פירש ר"ת כל שעבר עליו לילה אחת בלא תבשיל, אפילו בשלו בו אתמול בערב, מיד בבקר אינו בן יומו.‏
>
> According to Rabenu Tam, one night without non kasher food is enough. For instance, if they coock something yesterday afternoon, we can make the hag'ala in morning.

ור"י פירש שצריך שישהא מעת לעת, וכן עיקר.

> Rabenu Yitschack thinks that we need a whole day (approximately 24h). This opinion is  stated in Halacha.

The Bet Yosef explains that even to use the vedsel with water today maintains the vessel as if it was used with non kosher food today andcwe need to wait again 24h

Answer (score 1):

I think חמץ קודם זמן איסור which is ערב פסח after 6th hour is different and  we do not need to wait 24 hours before Kashering, before that time ,  since  חמץ it’s נט בר נט דהיתר

Comment: Hey Moris, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for the answer! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Based on what I know about this site from my time here, it would be tremendously appreciated if you could explain the Hebrew concepts to users who may not understand them, as well as provide a source that says this.